# Session/startup custom code does not run (correctly) on Xubuntu 16.04/18.04

Tags: xubuntu, compiz, autostart

In a nutshell: it appears code I add to my session & startup menu does not get run (correctly). Some examples:

```
compiz --replace & 
dropbox stop && dbus-launch dropbox start &
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover &
```

When I a) reboot or b) log out, I have to run this code via xfrun regardless to have it function. I have been having this issue in my previous install of Xubuntu 16.04 and now still in my new install 18.04 & I would like to finally fix it.

I have been searching on google trying to find some sort of log to try and trouble shoot this, but so far no dice. I have been using search terms like:

```
xubuntu autostart applications log
xubuntu session log
xubuntu startup log
xubuntu troubleshoot application autostart
xubuntu application autostart not working
```

I found and tried the solutions in:

- [Edit .desktop files in /etc/xdg/autostart](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2329195)
- compiz specific a) add & -> can't find source anymore, sorry
- compiz specific b) [dconf reset -f /org/compiz/](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144527)
- [I never save sessions, and clearing the session does not help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264144/autostart-program-in-xfce)
- Suggestion I have found in multiple places (e.g. [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188834)) is that it might have to do with the order in which scripts are run. However, this seems unlikely to me as these are multiple unrelated commands with the same problem. To check, I renamed all my custom fixes with zz_ to get them last in the list (although opinions seem divided on whether that affects the load order) and restarted my session. No dice.
- [desktop files in ~/.config/autostart/ are all created and fine](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2015/05/msg00358.html) None of the names contain spaces (a bug I read about elsewhere, can’t find source back, sorry).
- As a sanity check, I added the ~/.config/autostart/ files to /etc/xdg/autostart but as I suspected that did not do anything at all.
- I could not find any mention of logs of the commands in autorun, although that would be insanely useful

I am running out of ideas. Perhaps I am missing something, or I do not know the one search term that would give me the solution. I am not a pro linux user by any stretch of the imagination, but I am trying to learn :). Any and all help much appreciated.

Thank you,
Narameh

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You are muddying the water needlessly by running several commands in the background and not providing output from each command. This is too broad IMHO. I recommend that you run each command separately and examine the output from each one to provide clues. Then open a new question as necessary for each failure. Cheers!

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Whether I add the commands 'in the background'  or not does actually not make a difference at all. The result is the same when I remove the end &'s. Secondly: if you could tell me how and where I could access the output of commands run on autostart that would be amazing. For reference, the commands run absolutely fine if run via xfrun or in terminal after startup.

Comment: Run compiz, open All Settings, Session and Startup, check "Automatically save session on logout". This worked for me.

Comment: @kodmanyagha thank you. It seems my compiz version only has 'session management' which was already enabled. I appreciate your comment on my dead topic though!

Comment: This topic indexed on google first page